# Selection API — каков алгоритм преобразования выделения в строку?

Tags: javascript

```js
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('foo'));
window.getSelection().addRange(range);

console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString());
```

```html
<div id="foo">Ва<p>ся</div>
```

В первом случае вывелось «Ва ся» раздельно, во втором — «Вася» слитно. Причём Chrome выводит «Ва сю» в две строки, а Firefox — в три строки, добавляя ещё одну пустую.

Стандартизировано ли такое различающееся поведение? Можно ли им управлять? Баг или фича? Есть ли какой-то конкретный список тегов, который может привести к такому разделению? (Для сравнения, `Ва<em>ся</em>` ничего не делит в обоих случаях.) Пробежка глазами по Selection API ничего толкового не дала.